# iCarousel stop at a index programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

Is there anyway to make a UIScrollView/iCarousel stop at a specific part or `index` or like here programmatically:
`([[images objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 75)`

Here is a how I scroll my iCarousel:

`[carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:-35 duration:10.7550f];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scroll to a specific index using

```
[carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:5 duration:10.0f];
```

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do though - your example code doesn't make any sense because in this code you are attempting to convert an image to an integer, which will just crash:

```
([[images objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 75)
```

Comment: sir, I want to be able to scroll the carousel depending on which/where/what the user picks corresponding to the image he wants.

Comment: How does the user pick an image? By tapping on it in the carousel?

Comment: Like a setting mode. The images are displayed in a UIImageView. Then when the user press that image, when the carousel scroll it will stop at that image or index

Comment: That's already built in. When a user taps an image that isn't already centered, the carousel will scroll to that image. You don't have to do anything to enable it.

Comment: I mean for example, The image in my carousel are separately display in another view. Like in a thumbnail. When I click that image in the thumbnail,  in my carousel that will where the carousel stop.

Comment: You should have an array of all images that the user wants to select (this can be an array of image names instead of images to save memory, but you need to be able to uniquely identify a specific image). Then when the user selects an image in one view, make a note of which index in that array they selected, then you can easily scroll to that index in the carousel in a different view.